# How to send multiple requests (Batch) in a single batch request

Tags: python, api, postman, batch-processing, jira-rest-api

We have two different set of API's as below:

GET : http://localhost:8080/rest/tests/1.0/testplan
GET : http://localhost:8080/rest/tests/1.0/testrun/search?fields=id,key,name

How i can send these 2 requests in a single request in python?

Note, This is an example for 2 API's, Similarly i should batch more than 10 API's.

Can anyone help to provide solution for this use case?